# ActionBarSherlock 4 ScrollingTextView

Tags: java, android, android-xml, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I recently upgraded my project from ABS 3.5 to ABS 4 but I've run into a problem that has had me pulling my hair out for a few days now. The main activity contains three tabs wit text. In 3.5 the text would scroll horizontally in their respective tabs, as the text is too long to fit in the tab at any one time. Since I upgraded to ABS 4 the text no longer scrolls, it instead shortens the word e.g "Messa...".

I can see that the ScrollingTextView class has been removed from com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget. I can see that the ScrollingTabContainerView has been added to this package but I don't know if this is provided as an alternative.

I have tried setting the `android:ellipsize` to `marquee` and setting the `marqueeRepeatLimit` to `marquee_forever` but it does not seem to work for me.

Does anyone know how to get this feature back running as I assume that it is still possible.

By the way, I mean that the text should scroll automatically, the user does not click and drag the tabs to scroll. Just to be clear :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as far as I can tell this feature has been completely removed in ABS 4 and has been replaced with the scrolling tabs. This is slightly disappointing as it gave a nice effect to the tabs to have the text scroll.